# How to disable past dates in `datepickr.js`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datepickr.js

Like the title says, I would like to disable past dates in a date-picker script.

Here what I do to create it:

```
new datepickr('datepick', {
  fullCurrentMonth: true,
  dateFormat: 'j-m-Y',
  minDate: 0 ,
  weekdays: [
    'Lunedì', 'Martedì', 
    'Mercoledì', 'Giovedì', 
    'Venerdì', 'Sabato', 
    'Domenica' 
  ],
  months: [ 
    'Gennaio', 'Febbraio',
    'Marzo', 'Aprile',
    'Maggio', 'Giugno',
    'Luglio', 'Agosto',
    'Settembre', 'Ottobre',
    'Novembre', 'Dicembre' 
  ],
});
```

And here is the entire script (from the internet, I don't remember where I found it).

```
/*
datepickr - pick your date not your nose
Copyright (c) 2012
*/

var datepickr = (function() {
  var datepickrs = [],
  currentDate = new Date(),
  date = {
    current: {
      year: function() {
        return currentDate.getFullYear();
      },
      month: {
        integer: function() {
          return currentDate.getMonth();
        },
        string: function(full) {
          var date = currentDate.getMonth();
          return monthToStr(date, full);
        }
      },
      day: function() {
        return currentDate.getDate();      
      }
    },
    month: {
      string: function(full, currentMonthView) {
        var date = currentMonthView;
        return monthToStr(date, full);
      },
      numDays: function(currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
        // checks to see if february is a leap year otherwise return the respective # of days
        return (currentMonthView == 1 && !(currentYearView & 3) && (currentYearView % 1e2 || !(currentYearView % 4e2))) ? 29 : daysInMonth[currentMonthView];
      }
    }
  },
  weekdays = ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Gio', 'Ven', 'Sab'],
    months= ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre'],
  daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
  suffix = { 1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd', 21: 'st', 22: 'nd', 23: 'rd', 31: 'st' },
  buildCache = [],
  handlers = {
    calendarClick: function(e) {
      if(e.target.className) {
        switch(e.target.className) {
          case 'prev-month':
          case 'prevMonth':
            this.currentMonthView--;
            if(this.currentMonthView < 0) {
              this.currentYearView--;
              this.currentMonthView = 11;
            }
            rebuildCalendar.call(this);
          break;
          case 'next-month':
          case 'nextMonth':
            this.currentMonthView++;
            if(this.currentMonthView > 11) {
              this.currentYearView++;
              this.currentMonthView = 0;
            }
            rebuildCalendar.call(this);
          break;
          case 'day':
            this.element.value = formatDate(new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, e.target.innerHTML).getTime(), this.config.dateFormat);
            this.close();
          break;
        }
      }
    },
    documentClick: function(e) {
      if(e.target != this.element && e.target != this.calendar) {
        var parentNode = e.target.parentNode;
        if(parentNode != this.calender) {
          while(parentNode != this.calendar) {
            parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
            if(parentNode == null) {
              this.close();
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  function formatDate(milliseconds, dateFormat) {
    var formattedDate = '',
    dateObj = new Date(milliseconds),
    format = {
      d: function() {
        var day = format.j();
        return (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
      },
      D: function() {
        return weekdays[format.w()].substring(0, 3);
      },
      j: function() {
        return dateObj.getDate();
      },
      l: function() {
        return weekdays[format.w()] + 'day';
      },
      S: function() {
        return suffix[format.j()] || 'th';
      },
      w: function() {
        return dateObj.getDay();
      },
      F: function() {
        return monthToStr(format.n(), true);
      },
      m: function() {
        var month = format.n() + 1;
        return (month < 10) ? '0' + month : month;
      },
      M: function() {
        return monthToStr(format.n(), false);
      },
      n: function() {
        return dateObj.getMonth();
      },
      Y: function() {
        return dateObj.getFullYear();
      },
      y: function() {
        return format.Y().toString().substring(2, 4);
      }
    },
    formatPieces = dateFormat.split('');

    foreach(formatPieces, function(formatPiece) {
      formattedDate += format[formatPiece] ? format[formatPiece]() : formatPiece;
    });

    return formattedDate;
  }

  function foreach(items, callback) {
    var i = 0, x = items.length;
    for(i; i < x; i++) {
      if(callback(items[i], i) === false) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  function addEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
    if(element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else if(element.attachEvent) {
      var fixedCallback = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault = (function(e) {
          return function() { e.returnValue = false; }
        })(e);
        e.stopPropagation = (function(e) {
          return function() { e.cancelBubble = true; }
        })(e);
        e.target = e.srcElement;
        callback.call(element, e);
      };
      element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, fixedCallback);
    }
  }

  function removeEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
    if(element.removeEventListener) {
      element.removeEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else if(element.detachEvent) {
      element.detachEvent('on' + eventType, callback);
    }
  }

  function buildNode(nodeName, attributes, content) {
    var element;

    if(!(nodeName in buildCache)) {
      buildCache[nodeName] = document.createElement(nodeName);
    }

    element = buildCache[nodeName].cloneNode(false);

    if(attributes != null) {
      for(var attribute in attributes) {
        element[attribute] = attributes[attribute];
      }
    }

    if(content != null) {
      if(typeof(content) == 'object') {
        element.appendChild(content);
      } else {
        element.innerHTML = content;
      }
    }

    return element;
  }

  function monthToStr(date, full) {
    return ((full == true) ? months[date] : ((months[date].length > 3) ? months[date].substring(0, 3) : months[date]));
  }

  function isToday(day, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    return day == date.current.day() && currentMonthView == date.current.month.integer() && currentYearView == date.current.year();
  }

  function buildWeekdays() {
    var weekdayHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();
    foreach(weekdays, function(weekday) {
      weekdayHtml.appendChild(buildNode('th', {}, weekday.substring(0, 2)));
    });
    return weekdayHtml;
  }

  function rebuildCalendar() {
    while(this.calendarBody.hasChildNodes()){
      this.calendarBody.removeChild(this.calendarBody.lastChild);
    }

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
    numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);

    this.currentMonth.innerHTML = date.month.string(this.config.fullCurrentMonth, this.currentMonthView) + ' ' + this.currentYearView;
    this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
  }

  function buildCurrentMonth(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    return buildNode('span', { className: 'current-month' }, date.month.string(config.fullCurrentMonth, currentMonthView) + ' ' + currentYearView);
  }

  function buildMonths(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    var months = buildNode('div', { className: 'months' }),
    prevMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'prev-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'prevMonth' }, '&lt;')),
    nextMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'next-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'nextMonth' }, '&gt;'));

    months.appendChild(prevMonth);
    months.appendChild(nextMonth);

    return months;
  }

  function buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    var calendarBody = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    row = buildNode('tr'),
    dayCount = 0, i;

    // print out previous month's "days"
    for(i = 1; i <= firstOfMonth; i++) {
      row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
      dayCount++;
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
      // if we have reached the end of a week, wrap to the next line
      if(dayCount == 7) {
        calendarBody.appendChild(row);
        row = buildNode('tr');
        dayCount = 0;
      }

      var todayClassName = isToday(i, currentMonthView, currentYearView) ? { className: 'today' } : null;
      row.appendChild(buildNode('td', todayClassName, buildNode('span', { className: 'day' }, i)));

      dayCount++;
    }

    // if we haven't finished at the end of the week, start writing out the "days" for the next month
    for(i = 1; i <= (7 - dayCount); i++) {
      row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
    }

    calendarBody.appendChild(row);

    return calendarBody;
  }

  function buildCalendar() {
    var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
    numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView),
    self = this;

    var inputLeft = inputTop = 0,
    obj = this.element;

    if(obj.offsetParent) {
      do {
        inputLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
        inputTop += obj.offsetTop;
      } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }

    var calendarContainer = buildNode('div', { className: 'calendar' });
    calendarContainer.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top: ' + (inputTop + this.element.offsetHeight) + 'px; left: ' + inputLeft + 'px; z-index: 100;';

    this.currentMonth = buildCurrentMonth(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView)
    var months = buildMonths(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);
    months.appendChild(this.currentMonth);

    var calendar = buildNode('table', null, buildNode('thead', null, buildNode('tr', { className: 'weekdays' }, buildWeekdays())));
    this.calendarBody = buildNode('tbody');
    this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
    calendar.appendChild(this.calendarBody);

    calendarContainer.appendChild(months);
    calendarContainer.appendChild(calendar);

    document.body.appendChild(calendarContainer);

    addEvent(calendarContainer, 'click', function(e) { handlers.calendarClick.call(self, e); });

    return calendarContainer;
  }

  return function(elementId, userConfig) {
    var self = this;

    this.element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    this.config = {
      fullCurrentMonth: true,
      dateFormat: 'F jS, Y'
    };
    this.currentYearView = date.current.year();
    this.currentMonthView = date.current.month.integer();

    if(userConfig) {
      for(var key in userConfig) {
        if(this.config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.config[key] = userConfig[key];
        }
      }
    }

    this.documentClick = function(e) { handlers.documentClick.call(self, e); }

    this.open = function(e) {
      addEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);

      foreach(datepickrs, function(datepickr) {
        if(datepickr != self) {
          datepickr.close();
        }
      });

      self.calendar.style.display = 'block';
    }

    this.close = function() {
      removeEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);
      self.calendar.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("abb").focus();
    }

    this.calendar = buildCalendar.call(this);

    datepickrs.push(this);

    if(this.element.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
      addEvent(this.element, 'focus', this.open);
    } else {
      addEvent(this.element, 'click', this.open);
    }
  }
})();
```

I've already tried with `minDate: 0` but it didn't work.

Some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know where you found it, how can you make sure that you are allowed to use it?

Comment: @jgillich I'm sure I was allowed.

Comment: Ok then it may be fine. But it is always a better idea to use code that is documented and maintained, its not like this is the only datepicker script out there. ;)

Comment: The repo for `datepickr.js`, by the way, is at: https://github.com/joshsalverda/datepickr

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the documentation of datepicker http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ how to use **minDate**.

When you are using datepicker.js you have to use **minDate** property already provided in the library.

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/UE4rD/) link i found googling.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
minDate:'0d'

$("#id").datepicker({ changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showOn: 'none', showButtonPanel: true,  minDate:'0d' });
```

And check it after

```
alert( $("#id").datepicker( "option", "minDate" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the minDate param to the new Datepicker obj like this:

```
new datepickr('datepick',
{
     fullCurrentMonth : true,
     dateFormat : 'j-m-Y',
     minDate: new Date(2007, 0, 1), //The format to pass in is: Year, Month (starting at 0), day
     weekdays : [ 'Lunedì', 'Martedì',
             'Mercoledì', 'Giovedì',
             'Venerdì', 'Sabato',
             'Domenica' ],
     months : [ 'Gennaio', 'Febbraio',
             'Marzo', 'Aprile',
             'Maggio', 'Giugno',
             'Luglio', 'Agosto',
             'Settembre', 'Ottobre',
             'Novembre', 'Dicembre' ],

 });
```